# Regex: Insert some string/words between html tags

Tags: notepad++, regex, html

I have this html tags:

```
</table>
   <p class="text_obisnuit2"><em>
```

I want to insert an html comments, so as to become:

```
</table>
  <!-- NEW TEXT -->  
   <p class="text_obisnuit2"><em>
```

**I made a regex but is not working:**

Find: `(<\/table>)(\s+\S+)(<p class="text_obisnuit2"><em>)`

Replace by: `\1 <!-- NEW TEXT --> \3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex can be improved like:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `</table>(\R\h*)\K(?=<p class="text_obisnuit2"><em>)`
- Replace with: `<!-- NEW TEXT -->$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
</table>            # literally
(\R\h*)             # group 1, any kid of linebreak and 0 or more horizontal spaces
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
(?=<p class="text_obisnuit2"><em>)  # positive lookahead, make sure we have this text after
```

**Replacement:**

```
<!-- NEW TEXT -->   # new value to be inserted
$1                  # content of group 1, a linebreak and horizontal spaces
```

---

This keeps the linebreak and number of horizontal spaces from original text.

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thank you @Toto

Answer (score 1):

FIND: `(</table>)(\r\s+)(<p class="text_obisnuit2"><em>)`

REPLACE BY: `\1\r\n\t <!-- NEW TEXT --> \r\n\t\3`

**or**

FIND: `(?s)(</table>)(.*)(<p class="text_obisnuit2"><em>)`

REPLACE BY: `\1\r\n\t <!-- NEW TEXT --> \r\n\t\3`

**or**

If you have something like this:

```
</tr>
 </table>
 <p class="text_obisnuit2"><em>
```

FIND: `(?s)(</tr>.*\K</table>)(.*)(<p class="text_obisnuit2"><em>)`

REPLACE BY: `\1\r\n\t <!-- NEW TEXT --> \r\n\t\3`

[image]